# pls-00306 error when trying to print output

Tags: oracle, plsql

This code block returns error pls-00306 wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'put_line':

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE  
   ch varchar2(16);
   cursor ebs_user_cur 
   is
   select xmlagg(xmlelement("r", ch)).extract('//text()').getstringval() 
from
(
  select distinct first_value(ch) over (partition by lower(ch))  
  from (
    select substr('abcd#efghijklmn#pqrstuvwxyzABC$DEFGHIJK$LMNPQR!STUVWXYZ1!23456789',
        level, 1)  ch
    from dual 
    connect by level <= 59
    order by dbms_random.value
  )
  where rownum <= dbms_random.value(18,18)
);
l_passwd   ebs_user_cur%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
open ebs_user_cur;
loop
fetch ebs_user_cur into l_passwd;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_passwd);
EXIT WHEN l_passwd%NOTFOUND;
END LOOP;
close ebs_user_cur;
END;
```

Where is mistake?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

1. You should give column alias in your cursors
2. You should specify exact field name in `l_passwd.{field_name}`:

```sql
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE  
   ch varchar2(16);
   cursor ebs_user_cur 
   is
   select xmlagg(xmlelement("r", ch)).extract('//text()').getstringval() 
    as res -- <<< see here
    from
    (
      select distinct first_value(ch) over (partition by lower(ch))  
      from (
        select substr('abcd#efghijklmn#pqrstuvwxyzABC$DEFGHIJK$LMNPQR!STUVWXYZ1!23456789',
            level, 1)  ch
        from dual 
        connect by level <= 59
        order by dbms_random.value
      )
      where rownum <= dbms_random.value(18,18)
    );
    l_passwd   ebs_user_cur%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  open ebs_user_cur;
  loop
    fetch ebs_user_cur into l_passwd;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_passwd.res); -- <<< .res here
    EXIT WHEN l_passwd%NOTFOUND;
  END LOOP;
  close ebs_user_cur;
END;
```